# This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode. when publishing to host

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5.2

For school we have to publish our sites on a specific hosting they provide.
but when I publish my site to that host. I get the following error:

`This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode.`

I can't change much from my account on the hosting. So is there a way to fix this in the project?
I tried changing it from integrated to classic. but that doesn't change much

It's with MVC version: 5.2.2.0

Comment: On which page are you getting this ?

Comment: All of them. or I didn't found any that doesn't have the error

Comment: So have you changed mode to integrated ?

Comment: Yep, now it's on Integrated. as default when creating a new project

Comment: This needs to be changed on IIS.

Comment: But what makes the project needing this? I have this problem even with a freshly created one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67665/discussion-between-mairaj-ahmad-and-kiwi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your application pool mode to integrated from IIS.

- Open IIS.
- Click your server name on top left.
- Click on application pools.
- Select pool of your website.
- Click on Basic settings on right side and change mode to integrated.